# C# - Create Dictionary<T, Manager<T>>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have a generic class named `Manager<T>`, and I want to create a dictionary that maps a type to an instance of the Manager class of this type.
I thought about creating a Dictionary class that derives from `Dictionary`, but overriding all of its methods seems overkill.
Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you want a `Dictionary<Type, Manager<>>` or something along that instead if you actually intend to use types as keys.

Comment: You need to have a command factory that will provide the correct Manager class to work on the type, assuming that the types can't implement a common interface.

Comment: Im pretty sure C# generic syntax doesnt support this in this instance, however this is the ideal here

Comment: C# only seems to supports the empty <> inside a typeof statement ie typeof(List<>) is valid however List<List<>>

Comment: the trouble with this is that what you really want to do is to create a dictionary to map Type to Manager<typeof(Type)> isnt supported by the language. ie you cant include typeof in the generic header. eg Dictionary<Type t,Manager<typeof(t)>> isnt actually syntactically valid even though its kinda the outcome you would like here

Comment: Preserving the genericness of the Manager internally doesn't matter here, it seems to me. As long as the type-unsafity is kept enclosed in the small area of this Dictionary wrapper, everything is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your dictionary needs to hold managers with mixed type arguments, you can implement an `IManager` interface in `Manager<T>`, make a `Dictionary<Type,IManager>`, and add a generic wrapper to cast instances back to `Maanger<T>`, like this:

```
interface IManager {
    // Properties and methods common to all Maanger<T>, regardless of T
}

class Manager<T> : IManager {
}

class Main {
    private readonly IDictionary<Type,IManager> managers =
        new Dictionary<Type,IManager>();

    bool TryGetManager<T>(Type key, out Manager<T> manager) {
        IManager res;
        return managers.TryGetValue(key, out res) ? ((Manager<T>)res) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt preserve the generic type from the dictionary does it?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor If I understood the question correctly, the idea was to store generic instances in a dictionary; having a generic dictionary was not a goal in itself. To that end, the sample does what the OP wants: he gets to look up a `Manager<T>` by the `Type` of his `T`, getting a generic back.

Comment: You actually lose the genericness entirely with this, eg string DoSomething(T val) would be converted to string DoSomething(object val) by IManager and even if you actually make a generic version you have to preserve the object version for the sake of the interface. TBH IManager would be much better as a marker interface, at least then the only impact would be a cast on the way out of the dictionary.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I think I know why you got confused: I declared `TryGetManager<T>(Type,T manager)` instead of `TryGetManager<T>(Type, Manager<T> manager)`. I have now fixed it. The interface is non-essential to the solution: he might as well have `object` in the dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary<Tkey,object> isn't particularly nice as it doesn't ensure any type safety on the stored item

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Think about it carefully: there's absolutely nothing else it can do. Unless you add a common interface as I suggested, `System.Object` would be the only common ancestor type of all `Manager<T>`.

Comment: Your solution would be much better if IManager was simply a marker interface ie empty, however it still kinda doesnt solve the problem

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Whether or not it should be a marker is up to the OP to decide. As far as solving the OP's problem, it's the *only* answer on the page that addresses the "create a dictionary that maps a type to an instance of the Manager class of this type" requirement.

Answer (score 2):

i think this is a case generics doesnt support nicely, prehaps this is what you want. You will need to store managers internally to this, for the storage prehaps use a `Dictionary<Type,Object>` or `Dictionary<Type,IManager>` where IManager is a marker (empty) interface applied to `Manager<T>` You will then need to cast this to the type T provided before returning it. I cant think of a good way to access this via an indexer so this may be the best you can get to

```
public class ManagerDictionary{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _managers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Manager<T> GetManager<T>()
    {
        if (_managers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return _managers[typeof(T)] as Manager<T>;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No manager of " + typeof(T).Name + " could be found");
    }

    public void AddManager<T>(Manager<T> manager)
    {
        _managers.Add(typeof(T),manager);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this address the "create a dictionary that maps a type to an instance of the Manager class of this type" requirement from the OP?

Comment: It doesnt create an IDictionary, what it does do is create a way of getting a provided instance of a specific Manager<T> for the type T which is what i understand the intent of the question to be

Comment: I think the header of the OP is misleading. Inside the post he clearly states: "I want to create a dictionary that maps a *type* to an instance of the *Manager class of this type*.", while the title suggests that he wants to map *an instance of type T* to an instance of the Manager class of this type. The former makes sense (and is in fact a common problem to solve), while the later does not make much sense outside of rather contrived examples.

Comment: I think the title is a little misleading

Comment: OK, now your solution looks almost like mine :):):)

Comment: I suppose it is similar... prehaps i didnt fully understand what you were getting at. I do however think that its important not to put any content into IManager if you have it as that will break type safety. I also think its important to wrap this in a class to group it together. Otherwise yes they are very similar so downvote removed

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you really need to have an interface that T derives from. Then your manager class can work with whatever concrete T you pass in.

```
class Manager<T> where T: IMyClass
```

This is good practice as the methods on the interface are what make T generic.

For more ideas you could look at the [Command Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx)

You are going to have some sort of switch or dictionary to maintain, but you should be able to get a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would make it:

```
class ManagerDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, Manager<T>> {

}
```

Comment: This does not address the "create a dictionary that maps a type to an instance of the Manager class of this type" requirement from the OP. The headline is misleading, because Dictionary<T,Manager<T>> is certainly *not* what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This will only map a single type to a manager of that type. ie it will allow mapping the string "hello"  to an instance of Manager<String> which isnt really the intention